# Crystal Report link report parameter with stored procedure parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, crystal-reports

I am using a third party program that will run Crystal Report. This program will pass a set of parameters to the Crystal Report, for example `ReportNumber`. I have to create a parameter with name of `ReportNumber` to be able to get the value. When the program runs and calls Crystal Report, it will automatically fill in this parameter value, so there will no longer be a popup to enter the parameter.

Then, I have a stored procedure in the Crystal Report. When I add this SP to CR, it will automatically create parameter e.g. `@ReportNumber`. If I run the report, it will show a popup to enter `@ReportNumber` as the SP requires it. My question is how do I link the parameter `ReportNumber` with `@ReportNumber`, such that I do not need to input it again?

It will be great if the solution does not use subreport, because I need to put subreports as well. This is due to CR does not support subreport inside subreport.